# Sending request from hubot http listener callback, "TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined"

Tags: coffeescript, hubot

I've been having issues trying to get my hubot instance to perform an http request while in a callback from a http listener.  My guess is that it is in the middle of a req/res cycle and unable to complete a different request.  Usually the robot object has the http method that allows for sending one, but I keep getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined"  In other hubot examples I've seen online, they refer to the use of the response object, but that is only the case inside of a chat listener and indeed when I attempt to use the response object it throws an error, "TypeError: res.http is not a function".  Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks!

```
  robot.router.post '/gitlab-incoming', (req, res) ->
data = {
  "request_type": req.body.object_kind,
  "status": req.body.object_attributes.state,
  "project_name": req.body.object_attributes.source.name,
  "branch_name": req.body.object_attributes.source_branch,
  "job_name": 'review_stop',
  "team_name": process.env.GITLAB_TEAM_NAME,
  "gitlab_ci_token": process.env.GITLAB_CI_TOKEN,
  "action": 'play',
  "project_id": "#{process.env.GITLAB_TEAM_NAME}%2F#{req.body.object_attributes.source.name}"
}
if data['status'] == 'merged'
  robot.http("https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/#{data['project_id']}/jobs")
  .header('Accept', 'application/json')
  .header('PRIVATE-TOKEN', data['gitlab_ci_token'])
  .get() (err, http_res, body) ->
    if err
      res.send 'Sorry. Unable to fetch the list of jobs from Gitlab'
    job_found = false
    job_id = undefined
```